# Add to Cart works but nothing in Show#Cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my `cart.rb` model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tutors

  def current_cart
    if session[:cart_id]
      @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    end
    if session[:cart_id].nil?
      @current_cart = Cart.create!
      session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
    end
    @current_cart
  end

  def add_tutor(tutor_id)
    tutor = Tutor.find(tutor_id)
    if tutor
      self.tutors << tutor
    end
    save
  end
end
```

And here's my `carts_controller.rb`

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @cart = current_cart
  end

  def checkout
    @cart = current_cart
    name = params[:checkout][:your_name]
    email = params[:checkout][:your_email]
    message = params[:checkout][:your_hp]
    ApplicationMailer.checkout(@cart, name, email, message).deliver
    flash[:success] = "We have received your request and will be in touch with you shortly!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def add_to_cart
    @cart = current_cart.add_tutor(params[:tutor_id])
    if @cart
      flash[:success] = "You have successfully added the tutor to your cart!"
      redirect_to tutors_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again!"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```

And here's the button for the add to cart function

```
<%= button_to "Shortlist Tutor", add_to_cart_path(:tutor_id => tutor.id), :method => :post %>
```

The add to cart function seems to work fine as it redirects me to the correct page and no errors or anything like that seems to show up. In my rails console i can see in the server that there isn't any rollback.

```
Processing by CartsController#add_to_cart as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"da3XDg69FSCrEyn39v8Apty4aX40TJH85BeW49x/4R3MElKYxip1w7rpbWRBYj5hhZDAivf7Bxn4FK1dkHyKpg==", "tutor_id"=>"3"}
  Cart Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  Tutor Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "tutors".* FROM "tutors" WHERE "tutors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
```

Thats what i see in the server. I'm really not quite sure why don't i see anything when i go to my carts#show view.

Would appreciate any help that i can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check what you are receiving in params[:tutor_id].

Looking at SQL statements that are executed it doesn't look like it is saving at all when invoking add_to_cart. It only carries out a SELECT on carts and tutor.

Comment: how do i check what i'm receiving in params[:tutor_id]?

Comment: Well there are so many methods of debugging but the simplest method would be just to do `puts params[:tutor_id]`

Comment: It seems like im receiving the tutor_id of the selected tutor. It returns the value '3' when clicked. 

`Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"os+fPD6P9SaeyhqeKVxh9as+2GrXwbPn5scfOwWyhqwbcBqq9hiVxY8wXg2ewV8y8hZxnhR2JQL6xCSFSbHtFw==", "tutor_id"=>"3"}
  Cart Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  Tutor Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "tutors".* FROM "tutors" WHERE "tutors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
3`

Comment: little confused as to how current_cart is set... do you have another helper method for this - maybe from an installed gem?

Comment: No i am not using any other gems. I followed the current_cart method through an online tutorial.

Comment: Out of interest what happens when you add `puts "cart_id = #{session[:cart_id]}"` at the beginning of Cart#current_cart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125360/discussion-between-henners66-and-angkiki).